# Check if numpy array is contiguous?

Tags: python, numpy, contiguous

How can I find out if a n-dimensional numpy array `Arr` is contiguous in C-style or Fortran-style?

Comment: Also look at the `strides`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[The numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html#numpy.ndarray.flags) states that it is possible to check whether an array is C-contiguous or Fortran-contiguous via the attribute `flags`:

```
Arr.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
Arr.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']
```

These attributes return a boolean indicating which of the two cases is true.

Comment: Excepts it is not a function, it is actually an attribute of the `numpy.ndarray` object, as your reported syntax (which is correct) suggests.

Comment: @norok2, you are right! I edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: And with some axis swapping it possible that neither will be True.  And both are True for a 1d array

Comment: there is also [numpy.ascontiguousarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html) which may sometimes be helpful.

Answer (score 13):

You can also try the `ndarray.data.contiguous` member. E.g. (on my machine):

```
arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)

print(arr.data.contiguous)  # True
print(arr.data.c_contiguous)  # True
print(arr.data.f_contiguous)  # False
```

(I can't find any information re: which numpy versions support this, even on their docs. Any leads welcome in the comments!)

Comment: Note: this will not work with `datetime64` arrays; you get `ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer`