# Numpy memory alocation for array elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-management

So recently I've been doing a project whera as optimisation I want to use numpy arrays instead of python list built-in. It would be a 2d array with fixed length in both axes. I also want to maximasie cashe use so that code is as fast as it can be. However when playing with id(var) function I gor unexpected results:

code:

```
 a = numpy.ascontiguousarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dtype=numpy.int32)
 for var in a:
    print(hex(id(var)))
```

returned:

```
x1aaba10d8f0
0x1aaba1f33d0
0x1aaba10d8f0
0x1aaba1f33d0
0x1aaba10d8f0
0x1aaba1f33d0
0x1aaba10d8f0
0x1aaba1f33d0
0x1aaba10d8f0
```

which to me it is super weird cus that would mean 2 variables are located in same memory block (is that even a thing ?). anyway - is it me not understanding it correctlly?

As a side question - can the original task of building 2d array be acheaved with less expensive method? Numpy arrays come with many functions I do not need. Only 2 things I need:

1. to be able to reverse it normally done with [::-1] syntax
2. check if one == other efficiently

Thank in advance for all the help :-)

Comment: Unfortunately you skipped the basic reading of `numpy`, such as how it is stored.  Your `a` does not store python objects, so `id(var)` is meaningless.  You haven't described how you construct your 2d array (or list), so we can't help you with that.  But it sure sounds like `ndarray` is not the right tool for you.  It isn't a drop in replacement for lists.

Comment: The data buffer for `a` is a 36 byte `c` array (9*4).  You don't access it directly.  Speed comes from using compiled numpy methods to iterate or otherwise manipulate it.  It does not  make much sense to talk  about just using a few numpy functions.  Iterating as you do is actually slower on an array.

Comment: An easy way of making a 2d array is `np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)`, or `np.zeros((3,4))`

Answer (score 1):

`id(var)` does not work as you think it is. Indeed, `id(var)` returns a unique ID for the specified object `var`, but `var` is not a cell of `a`. **`var` is a Python object referencing a cell of `a`**. Note that `a` does not contains such objets as it would be too inefficient (and data would not be contiguous as requested). The reason why you see duplicated IDs is that previous `var` object as been recycled.

Comment: Thx man, I did further research and indeed it is as u said. Is there a way I can make sure that element of array continous? Ofther than documentation of course.

Comment: You can try the approach provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304154) or look the information stored in `a.__array_interface__`. But not that Numpy arrays should always be contiguous. However, Numpy *views* are not always contiguous.

Comment: OP, don't worry about whether arrays are contiguous, or about caching.  At least not until you learn to use numpy arrays for basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The kinds of arrays that you really want are unclear, nor is the purpose.  But talk of contiguous (or continuous) and caching, suggests that you aren't clear about how Python works.

First, Python is object oriented, all the way down.  Integers, strings, lists are all objects of some class, with associated methods, and attributes.  For builtin classes we have little say about the storage.

Let's make a small list:

```
In [89]: alist = [1,2,3,1000,1001,1000,'foobar']
In [90]: alist
Out[90]: [1, 2, 3, 1000, 1001, 1000, 'foobar']
```

A list has a data buffer that stores references (pointers if you will) to objects else where in memory.  The `id` may give some idea of where, it shouldn't be understood as a 'pointer' in the `c` language sense.

For this list:

```
In [91]: [id(i) for i in alist]
Out[91]: 
[9784896,
 9784928,
 9784960,
 140300786887792,
 140300786888080,
 140300786887792,
 140300786115632]
```

1,2,3 have small id values because Python has initialized small integers (up to 256) at the start.  So all uses will have that unique id.

```
In [92]: id(2)
Out[92]: 9784928
```

Within the list creation `1000` appears to be unique, but not so outside of that context.

```
In [93]: id(1001)
Out[93]: 140300786888592
```

Looks like the string is cached as well - but that's just the interpreter's choice, and we shouldn't count on it.

```
In [94]: id('foobar')
Out[94]: 140300786115632
```

The reverse list is a new list, with its own pointer array.  But the references are same:

```
In [95]: rlist = alist[::-1]
In [96]: rlist
Out[96]: ['foobar', 1000, 1001, 1000, 3, 2, 1]
In [97]: rlist[5],id(rlist[5])
Out[97]: (2, 9784928)
```

Indexing actions like `[::-1]` should just depend on the number of items in the list.  It doesn't depend on where the value actually point to.  Same for other copies.  Even appending to the array is relatively time independent (it maintains growth space in the data buffer).  Actually working with the objects in the list may be depend on where they are stored in memory, but we have little say about that.

A "2d" list is actually a list with list elements; nested lists.  The sublists are stored else where in memory, just like strings and numbers.  In that sense the nested lists are not contiguous.

So what about arrays?

```
In [101]: x = np.arange(12)
In [102]: x
Out[102]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [104]: x.__array_interface__
Out[104]: 
{'data': (57148880, False),
 'strides': None,             # default (8,)
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (12,),
 'version': 3}
In [105]: x.nbytes     # 12*8 bytes
Out[105]: 96
```

`x` is a `ndarray` object, with attributes like `shape`, `strides` and `dtype`.  And a data buffer.  In this case is a `c` array 96 bytes long, at "57148880`.  We can't use that number, but I find it useful when comparing this` array_interface`dict across arrays.  A`view` in particular will have the same, or related value.

```
In [106]: x.reshape(3,4)
Out[106]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [107]: x.reshape(3,4).__array_interface__['data']
Out[107]: (57148880, False)
In [108]: x.reshape(3,4)[1,:].__array_interface__['data']
Out[108]: (57148912, False)     # 32 bytes later
```

The array data buffer has actual values, not references.  Here with `int` dtype, each 8 bytes is interpreted as a 'int64' value.

Your `id` iteration effectively asks for a list, `[x[i] for i in range(n)]`.  An element of an array has to be "unboxed", and is a new object, type `np.int64`.  While not an array, it does have a lot of properties in common with a 1 element array.

```
In [110]: x[4].__array_interface__
Out[110]: 
{'data': (57106480, False),
 ...
 'shape': (),....}
```

That `data` value is unrelated to `x`'s.

As long as you use `numpy` methods on existing arrays, speeds are good, often 10x better than equivalent list methods.  But if you start with a list, it takes time to make an array.  And treating the array like list is slow.

And the reverse of `x`?

```
In [111]: x[::-1].__array_interface__
Out[111]: 
{'data': (57148968, False),
 'strides': (-8,),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (12,),
 'version': 3}
```

It's a new array, but with a different `strides` (-8,), and `data` points to the end of the buffer, `880+96-8`.